# iOS 7 Multipeer Connectivity- MCNearbyServiceBrowser finds itself?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, multipeer-connectivity

I have an app that's using the iOS 7 Multipeer Connectivity framework to advertise itself as well as browse for other devices. Why does my `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` instance find itself (the device the app is running on) and call the `browser:foundPeer...` delegate method? If I log the actual `PeerID` that I create to start advertising my device, as well as the discovered `PeerID` in the delegate method, they have different unique IDs but the same display name. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you found why this was happening?

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common unfortunately and is due to the underlying bonjour discovery service mechanism.  This really depends on a bunch of factors, including certain network devices that re-broadcast bonjour availability.

The best way to avoid this in your app is to use a unique string for your MCPeerID (I typicall use a new UUID string) and check the display name of each peerID against your local one before displaying it in your peer browser UI.

In swift it would look like this

let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString

self.peer = MCPeerID(displayName: uuid)

...

... when you get the found peer message from your session delegate:

if peerID.displayName != self.peer.displayName {
    ... add the peer to your available peers array here
}